# How do you detect when simple objects intersect in ruby 2D?

Tags: ruby, collision-detection, ruby2d

So I'm a beginner to ruby and I was playing around with collision detection in ruby 2d. I have a controllable square and a square that stays still. My question is how do to detect when the square collides with the circle.

This is my main code the rest is just controls to move the square

```
    @square = Square.new(x: 10, y: 20, size: 25, color: 'blue')

    @circle = Circle.new(x: 100, y: 100, radius: 10, color: 'red')

    @x_speed = 0
    @y_speed = 0

    game = Game.new


    class Game
        @score = 0
    end
```

and this is what is updating,

```
    update do
      if game.square_hit_circle?(square.x, square.y)
        puts "hit"
      end
    end
```

Here is what square_hit_circle? means

```
    def square_hit_circle?(x, y)
      @circle_x == x && @circle_y == y
    end
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `#square_hit_circle?` so we can see what might be wrong with it. Or have you not defined it yet and want help to do so? If so, can you figure out the mathematics of checking whether a square and circle intersect, and we can help you translate that into Ruby?

Comment: You need to clarify your question (by editing it). Something like, "given a circle and a square in a two-dimensional plane I wish to determine if there is a point that is within both the circle and square, including the possibility that a point is on both the circumference of the circle and on a side of the square. The circle is described by the coordinates of its center and its radius; the square by the coordinates of its four corners." You should also remove the links to the videos as they are irrelevant. I'll have an answer for you later.

Comment: Thanks so much i clarified my question

Comment: in `<main>': uninitialized constant Game (NameError) is my error

Comment: Use the `contains?(x, y)` method. It's available for all the ruby2d shapes and image Class.

Comment: I'm sorry I said how I don't really know ruby that well I just started. How would you do the contains method?

Comment: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby2d/0.9.2/Ruby2D/Circle#contains%3F-instance_method

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be of interest to provide a solution that does not make use of the `ruby2d` gem, so show how the required calculations are performed.

**Example data**

Suppose

```
center = [2, 7]
radius = 4

corners = [[1,3], [5,3], [3,1], [3,5]]
```

This looks like the following, with `Y` the center of the circle and the `X`'s the corners of the square.

```
7    Y
6   
5        X
4         
3  X           X    
2                
1        X              
0  1  2  3  4  5
```

**Determine the sides of the rectangle**

Select any of these corners (the first, say):

```
first, *rest = corners
  #=> [[1, 3], [5, 3], [3, 1], [3, 5]] 
first
  #=> [1, 3] 
rest
  #=> [[5, 3], [3, 1], [3, 5]]
```

Determine which corner is farthest from `c1`:

```
x1, y1 = first
farthest = rest.max_by { |x,y| (x-x1)**2 + (y-y1)**2 }
  #=> [5, 3]
```

Compute the sides of the square as arrays of endpoints:

```
rest.delete(farthest)
  #=> [5, 3] 
rest
  #=> [[3, 1], [3, 5]] 
sides = [first,farthest].product(rest)  
  #=> [[[1, 3], [3, 1]],
  #    [[1, 3], [3, 5]],
  #    [[5, 3], [3, 1]],
  #    [[5, 3], [3, 5]]]
```

Let's make a method to do this.

```
def sides(corners)
  first, *rest = corners
  x1, y1 = first
  farthest = rest.max_by { |x,y| (x-x1)**2 + (y-y1)**2 }
  rest.delete(farthest)
  [first,farthest].product(rest)
end

sides(corners)  
  #=> <as above>
```

**Compute intercept and slope for the lines coincident with the sides of the square**

For each of these sides there is a line in space that is coincide with the side. Each of these lines is described by an intercept `i` and a slope `b`, such that for any value of `x` the point `[x, y]` is on the line if `y = i + b*x`. We can compute the intercept and slope for each of these lines.

```
def compute_line(side)
  (ux,uy), (vx,vy) = side
  b = ux==uy ? 0.0 : (uy - vy).fdiv(ux - vx)
  [uy - b*ux, b]
end

sides.map { |side| compute_line(side) }
  #=> [[4.0, -1.0], [2.0, 1.0], [-2.0, 1.0], [8.0, -1.0]]
```

Note:

```
i, b = lines.first
  #=> [4.0, -1.0] 
i + b*0
  #=> 4.0 (the point [0, 4.0]) 
i + b*1
  #=> 3.0 (the point [1, 3.0]) 
i + b*2
  #=> 2.0 (the point [2, 2.0])
i + b*3  
  #=> 1.0 (the point [3, 1.0])
i + b*4
  #=> 0.0 (the point [4, 0.0])
```

**Compute the points where the circle intersects lines coincident with the sides**

Let

```
cx, cy = center
  #=> [2, 7]
```

Suppose we consider a side for which the coincident line has intercept `i` and slope `s`. We then have the quadratic expression:

<sub>(cx-x)<sup>2</sup> + (cy-i-s*x)<sup>2</sup> = radius<sup>2</sup></sub>

By defining:

<sub>e = cy - i</sub>

the equation reduces to:

<sub>cx<sup>2</sup> - 2*cx*x + x<sup>2</sup> + e<sup>2</sup> -  2*e*s*x + s<sup>2</sup>*x<sup>2</sup> = radius<sup>2</sup></sub>

or

<sub>(1 + s<sup>2</sup>)*x<sup>2</sup> + 2*(-cx -e*s)*x + cx<sup>2</sup> + e<sup>2</sup> - radius<sup>2</sup> = 0</sub>

or

<sub>a*x<sup>2</sup> + b*x + c = 0</sub>

where:

<sub>a = (1 + s<sup>2</sup>)</sub>

<sub>b = -2*(cx + e*s)</sub>

<sub>c = cx<sup>2</sup> + e<sup>2</sup> - radius<sup>2</sup></sub>

The real root or roots, if it/they exist, are given by the [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation). First compute the *discriminate*:

<sub>d = b<sup>2</sup> - 4*a*c</sub>

If the discriminate is negative the quadratic has *no real roots* (only *complex roots*). Here that means the circle is not large enough to intersect the line that is coincident with this side.

If the discriminate `d` is positive, there are two real roots (one real root only if `d` is zero). Let:

<sub>w = d<sup>1/2</sup></sub>

The roots (values of `x`) are:

<sub>(-b + w)/(2*a)</sub>

and

<sub>(-b - w)/(2*a)</sub>

Let's wrap this in a method:

```
def circle_and_line_intersections(center, radius, side)
  i, s = compute_line(side)
  cx, cy = center
  e = cy - i
  a = 1 + s**2
  b = -2*(cx + e*s)
  c = cx**2 + e**2 - radius**2 
  d = b**2 - 4*a*c
  return [] if d < 0
  return [-b/(2*a)] if d.zero?
  w = Math.sqrt(d)
  r1 = (-b + w)/(2*a)
  r2 = (-b - w)/(2*a)
  [[r1, i + s*r1], [r2, i + s*r2]] 
end

sides.map { |side| circle_and_line_intersections(center, radius, side) }
  #=> [[[ 0.82287, 3.17712], [-1.82287, 5.82287]],
  #    [[ 5.89791, 7.89791], [ 1.10208, 3.10208]],
  #    [],
  #    [[4.28388, 3.71611], [-1.28388, 9.28388]]]
```

It remains to do the following.

**Determine if one of the points of intersection is on a side**

That is simple and straightforward:

```
def on_side?(pt, side)
  low, high = side.map(&:first).sort
  (low..high).cover?(pt.first)
end
```

For example:

```
on_side?([0.82287, 3.17712], sides[0])
  #=> false
on_side?([1.10208, 3.10208], sides[1])    
  #=> true
```

**Putting it all together**

```
def intersect?(center, radius, corners)
  sides(corners).any? do |side|
    circle_and_line_intersections(center, radius, side).any? { |pt|
    on_side?(pt, side) }
  end
end

intersect?(center, radius, corners)
  #=> true
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confused. How do I put this in my code? Do I do it with a new file?

Comment: You could do that. Create a file (say) `intersect_circle_and_square.rb` containing the methods I've created above: `intersect?`, `sides`, `compute_line`, `circle_and_line_intersections` and `on_side?`. `intersect_circle` needs to be a public method; the others are best private methods. In you code execute the method [Kernel#require](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require) or [require_relative](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) Alternatively, you could simply add those methods to your Ruby file.